# Atomicity through object segregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, jpa, stored-procedures, atomic

I am facing a problem I don't know how to solve efficiently that involves an heavy use of the DBMS. I have a long running procedure refreshing (through bulk inserts/deletes/updates) many tables. Such tables are accessed by a back-end reading data from the DB; having clean information is essential; reading stale data is not a problem, the important part is to avoid reading partially updated information.

I am trying to achieve some sort of publishing mechanism whose purpose is to guarantee atomicity and avoid reading partially recomputed data (that may change or disappear). I need to guarantee the back-end reads data atomically w.r.t. this recomputing procedure.

I am pondering about replicating a classic solution of in-memory object segregation that basically separates old and new objects in two distinct memory areas, let them be A and B. All read operations are carried out on A, writes are carried out on B; after the procedure has finished the role of the two areas is swapped. Consequently, reads are always supported by stale or refreshed data and intermediate results are never read.

I think I should employ this kind of strategy because when the procedure updates the DB, transactions from the back-end tend to time-out due to the high contingency between transactions. I think separating data physically would improve this aspect too. I also suspect that `segregation` is not the proper word for describing the strategy I want to employ but in the context of garbage collectors this problem is often solved and named this way.

The obvious solution is to duplicate all tables and choose the working version of the table to carry out queries, perhaps inside a stored procedure. This solution however comes with the problem of rewriting all queries as store procedures and employ cursors... Another problem comes in the back-end where the technology I am using (JPA) is quite inflexible due to the high amount of native queries I had to write.

The question is: is there a convenient way to achieve this sort of publishing mechanism through features of SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply activate optimistic locking in your database using the command

```
ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
```

Once your transaction processing all data is complete, the new data will be exposed to users. During processing your users will be able to read old data.

No need to reinvent the wheel by creating a gas factory!!!!

Comment: I didn't know the existence of this flag. I turned it on and I started testing the joint behaviour of the database and the back-end.

Comment: @Chaos were the tests successful?

Comment: Definitely! Using this flag I took advantage a sophisticated DB feature I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Beware of one thing... all transactions will use the optimistic locking instead of pessimistic. The behaviour of process will not be exactlly the same if you use explicit transactions for some other code in your application. Particularly the READ COMMITTED is always transform as a REPEATABLE READ. Another feture to survey is the tempdb storage that will incresa notably because its stores the data version in use in snapshot transactions (resulting from optimistic locking).

Comment: Thanks you for the suggestion, I'll add it to the TODO list. Fortunately, I did not employ explicit transactions elsewhere.